# Loop only appending to one element rather than multiple

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

so I can't seem to figure this one out exactly. I want to append buttons to every container that doesn't have a null id. So in the list of contents there are two items and I would like to append buttons. The problem is that it only appends to the one, the last item in the list. So my question is to why? and how to fix it.

**Example Data Set**

Contents

```
0:{item_uuid: null, label: "11"}
1:{item_uuid: "49b661aa-222b-4c3c-a3cc-92db229c500e", label: "24"}
2:{item_uuid: null, label: "25"}
3:{item_uuid: null, label: "31"}
4:{item_uuid: "49b661aa-222b-4c3c-a3cc-92db229c500e", label: "43"}
5:{item_uuid: null, label: "44"}
```

**The Code**

```
 for (var i = 0; i < contents.length; i++) {
      if (contents[i].item_uuid !== null) {
           $('#' + contents[i].label).append(button);
           button.setAttribute("class", "button");
      }
    }
```

Comment: Works fine for me. http://jsbin.com/cemulifuki/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: your code works fine .. check if you have both the ids 24 and 43 in your page

Comment: Hmmmm ya that's a little confusing. Maybe something else in the code is breaking this functionality. Kind of a weird interaction though

Comment: Ya that's where I might be at a loss. It found both Ids I was looking for and only appends to the button to the last id.

Comment: @SulimanSharif i had some strange result when trying to append the same button twice, that's why i create it in the loop. You may want to make sure you're not appended the same button to multiple containers.

Comment: @bassxzero that was it. Ya I declared the variable button outside of the loop and it just appends the button elsewhere. Thanks this also fixed my dragging buttons issue :)

Comment: @SulimanSharif I made it an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works, but I had some strange results when trying to append the same button twice, that's why i create it in the loop. You may want to make sure you're not appended the same button to multiple containers.

E.G

```
 for (var i = 0; i < contents.length; i++) {
      if (contents[i].item_uuid !== null) {
        var button = $('<button>blah</button>');
           $('#' + contents[i].label).append(button);
           //button.setAttribute("class", "button");
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

May be create the button object inside the for loop. otherwise it uses the same button instance and will append only to the last one.

```
for (var i = 0; i < contents.length; i++) {
      if (contents[i].item_uuid !== null) {
           var button = createElement(....); //create it here
           $('#' + contents[i].label).append(button);
           button.setAttribute("class", "button");
      }
    }
```